# wrong execution order when bound maven assembly plugin twice to package phase

Tags: java, maven

I want to use proguard maven plugin to execute between 2 assembly descriptor (one of folder format and one of zip format) so I define my pom:

```
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>raw-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <finalName>raw</finalName>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/assemble/raw.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>proguard</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <options>
                    <option>@${project.build.directory}/raw/proguard/proguard.cfg</option>
                </options>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>distro-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <finalName>distro</finalName>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/assemble/distro.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But the maven assembly plugin always executes 2 descriptor before proguard plugin.

I use Maven 3.2.2

Thanks,

Comment: Package is spelled wrong in proguard

Comment: I edited the question, just a typo. sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When determining run order, Maven runs goals bound to earlier phases in the lifecycle first.  If multiple goals are bound to the same phase, then they run in the order they are listed in the POM.

When you want to run a plugin more than once, you don't add the plugin twice as you've shown, you put multiple executions in a single plugin.  If you want the proguard plugin to execute before the assemblies, you may bind the goals to an earlier phase (e.g. `prepare-package`).  If the phase must be `package` for some reason, then the proguard plugin config must appear before the assembly plugin config in the file.

If you need the first assembly execution to run before the proguard plugin execution, and the second assembly execution after, then you need to use two phases.  The proguard plugin config needs to appear in the file before the assembly plugin, and the execution should use phase `package`.  The first assembly execution should use `prepare-package`, the second `package`.

This is your POM rearranged to work, with everything bound to the `package` phase as was shown in the original question.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
        <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>  <!-- fixed spelling -->
                <goals>
                    <goal>proguard</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <options>
                <option>@${project.build.directory}/raw/proguard/proguard.cfg</option>
            </options>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

     <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>raw-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <finalName>raw</finalName>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/assemble/raw.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>distro-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <finalName>distro</finalName>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/assemble/distro.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: yes, I did the same instead of prepare-package I used test. prepare-package is better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Package is spelled wrong in program

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
        <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>packge</phase>    <--- Spelling Issue
```

Comment: Jeff your answer looks okay, and may contribute to the problem.